# Refactoring WHERE clause in T-SQL for Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, dry

I am currently implementing a heavy-duty `WHERE` clause involving 30 fields from a table, is there a way to refactor:

```
WHERE (
        (table.field1 LIKE "*" & Forms!SearchForm!txt_box1 & "*" 
                               Or Forms!SearchForm!txt_box1 Is Null) 
    AND (table.field2 LIKE "*" & Forms!SearchForm!txt_box2 & "*" 
                               Or Forms!SearchForm!txt_box2 Is Null) 
    AND ...
```

And so on until I get to the last field (31). Any ideas on how to implement a DRY method here?

Comment: Are the text boxes named box1, box2, etc, and same with field? (if yes, then a loop can be written to handle this). If not, then a different approach can be used.

Comment: Yeah, that code is basically what I have in my query which populates a subform whenevever the search button is clicked.  A user opens the form can fill in whatever data they want in each field and then search.  I would use more specific names for each field if that weren't already legacy'd in.  Users know what Field19 is and prefer it over AccountName.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a search form with 30 unbound textboxes that users enter criteria and then you build a where clause based on what was entered? If so, I have a methodology that I use for that case.

Comment: Yes that is what I have, I had another question on this forum about what a better approach would be and nothing came of it.  This is somewhat useful compared to what users do now, which is open the text files and manually search delimited records, not knowing which delimiter corresponds to what field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I typically do is name each control the same as the field to be included in the filter and set the tag property to the data type. Then loop through the controls.

    `Dim ctL As Access.Control
    Dim strWhere As String
    For Each ctL In Me.Controls
    If ctL.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctL.ControlType = acComboBox Then
        If Nz(ctL,"") <> "" Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & ctL.Name & "="
            If ctL.Tag = "Text" Then
                strWhere = strWhere & "'" & Replace(ctL, "'", "''") & "'"
            ElseIf ctL.Tag = "Date" Then
                strWhere = strWhere & "#" & ctL & "#"
            Else
                strWhere = strWhere & ctL
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next
    strWhere = Mid(strWhere, 6)`

Comment: I can kind of see what you did.  You programmed it into the VBA though, I have all of this implemented directly into a query and didn't use VBA for this portion of the form.  

Is it possible to structure a loop just in the query's SQL itself?

Comment: Queries can't perform loops in a where clause. Trying to include so many conditionals in the where clause makes it very inefficient and difficult to maintain, especially for the number of fields that you need to include. This method is very efficient, easily maintainable and scalable.

Comment: That makes sense.  When I get in tomorrow i will rework the form to include your implementation and come back if I have any more questions, thanks again!